# ActiveX ListControl events no longer work after windows update

Tags: javascript, windows-7, internet-explorer-9, activex, windows-update

I have an ActiveX ListControl on my web page whose double-click event no longer works after a recent windows update.  The update only affects Internet Explorer on Windows 7 (another user with Vista is fine, everyone else with 7 sees the same behavior).  I had a double-click event wired up to my control like so:

```
<script for="ListControl" event="DblClick" language="JavaScript">
    // interpret double-clicks as an "edit" request:
    Edit();
</script>
```

I've also tried this to no avail:

```
function ListControl::DblClick()
{
    Edit();
}
```

The site is not being blocked by the pop-up blocker and I've added it to my list of trusted sites.

I suspect that one of the recent security updates is to blame.  Has anyone else experienced this or found a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the link offered by user1601402, I found that this command resolves the issue:

```
regsvr32 c:\windows\syswow64\mscomctl.ocx
```

This is a temporary workaround in my opinion.  If a better solution comes along I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's a problem with Microsoft update (as if they will ever admit it!)  I have a company wide VB application in which I experienced the same issue; double-clicks in ActiveX controls do not fire the referenced procedures.  This happened this morning on all machines set to auto-update.  After performing system restores to the point before the updates the double-clicks perform as expected.

I am going to try some of the solutions offered [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/security-update-for-mscomctlocx-kb2597986-ms12-060/6dadedda-7bfa-4569-91d8-a31ebcf6a08a)

Easy solution is to do a System Restore but this leaves you vulnerable without the updated Security releases.